# php excel com_exception: unable to lookup 'Workbooks': Access is denied

Tags: php, windows, excel, com

I am trying to use PHP's COM interface to query a database and create pivot tables from the data in an Excel Workbook.

I have configured the DCOM settings on the local machine to grant the user Local Access, Local Launch, and Local Activation privileges as well as Full Control of Configuration Permissions. I have also tried all three Identity settings.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php

$application = new COM("Excel.Application") or die("Unable to load Excel.");
$workbook = $application->Workbooks;
$workbook = $workbook->Add();
$sheet = $workbook->Worksheets(1);
$sheet->Activate();
$application->Quit();

?>
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Unable to lookup `Workbooks': Access is denied.
```

This is different than error I was getting before which told me that I didn't have access to the Excel COM object. Setting the permissions fixed that.

Environment is:

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- Excel 2010 (64-bit)
- PHP 5.5.9 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

I never was able to solve this, so we had to come up with a different solution and it actually is more stable and performs better. Hope it helps anyone else that may run into the same issue.

Our database is MySQL (but this should be possible with most databases), so we moved our query into its own script and used the mysql client to write the results directly to a file.
We then created an excel template with a data connection to the file and used the connection as the data source for the pivot tables.
Lastly we wrote a short vbscript to open the template, refresh the pivot tables, then and save the file as a new copy.

This had the added benefit of allowing us to make stylistic changes using Excel's interface, which was much faster than doing it programmatically.